# How to track user activity on a webpage with Javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery

i want to track the user activity on page. 
on webpage there are various chapters in single video.
i want to keep track on when user started watching a chapter and when ended it.
and when user selected other chapter.

i am confused how to start tracking.

Comment: [Google analytics](https://www.google.co.uk/analytics/#?modal_active=none). It's free an simply involves a dozen lines of javascript dropped on your page.

Comment: The first step is google it,  second, come up with your solution. third, if you find any error, post it on stack overflow. Do not ask how to do it .